# bind ng-model to index in repeater

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a row of menu items that can be reordered by drag and drop. How can I bind a field called order in my model to the index?

this throws errors for me

```
<menu-row ng-repeat="i in menus"></ng-repeadt>
```

int the directive template:

```
<input field="hidden" name="order" ng-model="i.order = $index" />
```

I get this error

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign?p0=i.order

But it does seem to bind the number ok. If I set the display it works.

Comment: You need to put the code you do have into the question or we won't really know where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign in the `ng-model`, instead, assign in `ng-init`

```
<input field="hidden" name="order" ng-init="i.order = $index" ng-model="i.order" />
```